# Hive insert query optimization with UNION ALL

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am doing a insert in a hive table selecting data from two other table. My

First query is:

```
"insert overwrite table table1
 select uniod.col1,uniod.col2 from (
 select col1, col2 from table2
 UNION ALL
 select col1, col2 from table3
 ) uniod; "
```

Second query is:

```
"insert overwrite table table1
 select col1, col2 from table2
 UNION ALL
 select col1, col2 from table3
 ; "
```

**My question:** Are these two queries the same in terms of performance or one is better than the other?

Comment: Fields of table1 are "col1" and "col2"

Comment: These queries are same. You can make subqueries running in parallel.  This will improve performance. Set set hive.exec.parallel=true; and  hive.exec.parallel.thread.number=8 (desired number of maximum allowed parallel threads)

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to check explain plans. Both have generated same explain plan. Even the insert statements are running in similar fashion. It might differ in earlier versions of hive.

```
explain select * from (
select * from departments
union all
select * from departments
) q;

STAGE DEPENDENCIES:   Stage-1 is a root stage   Stage-0 depends on stages: Stage-1

STAGE PLANS:   Stage: Stage-1
    Map Reduce
      Map Operator Tree:
          TableScan
            alias: departments
            Statistics: Num rows: 14 Data size: 1538 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
            Select Operator
              expressions: department_id (type: int), department_name (type: string)
              outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1
              Statistics: Num rows: 14 Data size: 1538 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
              Union
                Statistics: Num rows: 28 Data size: 3076 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                Select Operator
                  expressions: _col0 (type: int), _col1 (type: string)
                  outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1
                  Statistics: Num rows: 28 Data size: 3076 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                  File Output Operator
                    compressed: false
                    Statistics: Num rows: 28 Data size: 3076 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                    table:
                        input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
                        output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
                        serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
          TableScan
            alias: departments
            Statistics: Num rows: 14 Data size: 1538 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
            Select Operator
              expressions: department_id (type: int), department_name (type: string)
              outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1
              Statistics: Num rows: 14 Data size: 1538 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
              Union
                Statistics: Num rows: 28 Data size: 3076 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                Select Operator
                  expressions: _col0 (type: int), _col1 (type: string)
                  outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1
                  Statistics: Num rows: 28 Data size: 3076 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                  File Output Operator
                    compressed: false
                    Statistics: Num rows: 28 Data size: 3076 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                    table:
                        input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
                        output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
                        serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe

  Stage: Stage-0
    Fetch Operator
      limit: -1
      Processor Tree:
        ListSink

Time taken: 0.124 seconds, Fetched: 55 row(s)

explain
 select * from departments
 union all
 select * from departments
 ;

STAGE DEPENDENCIES:
  Stage-1 is a root stage
  Stage-0 depends on stages: Stage-1

STAGE PLANS:
  Stage: Stage-1
    Map Reduce
      Map Operator Tree:
          TableScan
            alias: departments
            Statistics: Num rows: 14 Data size: 1538 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
            Select Operator
              expressions: department_id (type: int), department_name (type: string)
              outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1
              Statistics: Num rows: 14 Data size: 1538 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
              Union
                Statistics: Num rows: 28 Data size: 3076 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                Select Operator
                  expressions: _col0 (type: int), _col1 (type: string)
                  outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1
                  Statistics: Num rows: 28 Data size: 3076 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                  File Output Operator
                    compressed: false
                    Statistics: Num rows: 28 Data size: 3076 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                    table:
                        input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
                        output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
                        serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
          TableScan
            alias: departments
            Statistics: Num rows: 14 Data size: 1538 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
            Select Operator
              expressions: department_id (type: int), department_name (type: string)
              outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1
              Statistics: Num rows: 14 Data size: 1538 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
              Union
                Statistics: Num rows: 28 Data size: 3076 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                Select Operator
                  expressions: _col0 (type: int), _col1 (type: string)
                  outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1
                  Statistics: Num rows: 28 Data size: 3076 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                  File Output Operator
                    compressed: false
                    Statistics: Num rows: 28 Data size: 3076 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                    table:
                        input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
                        output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
                        serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe

  Stage: Stage-0
    Fetch Operator
      limit: -1
      Processor Tree:
        ListSink

Time taken: 0.064 seconds, Fetched: 55 row(s)
```